# Drush make directory is not writable

Tags: permissions

I am running a drush make and getting the following error

```
Directory /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/geoslate/sites/default exists, but is not writable. Please check directory permissions.                                 [error]
Unable to copy /tmp/make_tmp_1365076314_515d695acefc3/__build__/sites/default to ./sites/default.                                                           [error]
Cannot move build into place
```

I am not an expert on permissions in the terminal, can you give me a hand to give the directory the write permisions. I have tried chmod -w /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/geoslate/sites/default and chmod u+x /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/geoslate/sites/default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
chmod +w <directory> solved the problem
```